# Fetching images from Parse and load them in view pager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a code in which i am displaying images through view pager. At the moment these images are in my drawable folders but what i want is to put them in parse and fetch them from there and display them. What edits should i make to my code as to achieve this.

Here is my code:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    Context context;
    private int[] GalImages = new int[] { R.drawable.one, R.drawable.two,
            R.drawable.three };

    ImageAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return GalImages.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((ImageView) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
                R.dimen.padding_medium);
        imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        imageView.setImageResource(GalImages[position]);
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
        return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
    }
}
```

Thank-you.

Comment: Did you try Picasso or Glide libraries for async image loading?

Comment: @Sone No, i didnt. Could you please refer me any tutorial or something?

Comment: Sure here is picasso tutorial http://square.github.io/picasso/ And for glide https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki

Comment: @sone is there any video tutorials on how to implement these?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this Picassao link, used to load images from all resources - sdcard, web and resource with round support. http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: could you refer me to any video tutorials on how to implement these?